# How to handle infinite child arrays to add datas using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, hapi.js

I have a payload structure to add datas into db, each object have name with child array, db should add each object with parent id. how to handle these array in loop adding data in database?

payload structure:

```
{
    "name": "food",
    "child_categories": [
        {
            "name": "non-frozen",
            "child_categories": [
               {
                   "name":"non-branded",
                    "child_categories": [
                        {
                            "name":"food-grains",
                            "child_categories": [
                                {
                                   "name":"rice"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "atta"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "maida"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "sooji"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"ragi"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "jower"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "bajra"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"salt&spices",
                             "child_categories": [
                                 {
                                     "name":"whole-spices"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"grounded-spices"
                                 }
                             ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dried-condiments",
                             "child_categories": [
                                 {
                                     "name":"salt"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"powders"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"sugar"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"jaggery"
                                 }

                             ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "edible-oil&ghee"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "lentils",
                            "child_categories":[
                                {
                                    "name":"all-dals"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"all-rajma"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"chanas"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"millets"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"soya"
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
               },
               {
                   "name":"branded",
                       "child_categories": [
                        {
                            "name":"food-grains",
                            "child_categories": [
                                {
                                   "name":"rice"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "atta"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "maida"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "sooji"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"ragi"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "jower"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "bajra"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"salt&spices",
                             "child_categories": [
                                 {
                                     "name":"whole-spices"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"grounded-spices"
                                 }
                             ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"dried-condiments",
                             "child_categories": [
                                 {
                                     "name":"salt"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"powders"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"sugar"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "name":"jaggery"
                                 }

                             ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "edible-oil&ghee"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "lentils",
                            "child_categories":[
                                {
                                    "name":"all-dals"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"all-rajma"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"chanas"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"millets"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"soya"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"snacks&cereals",
                            "child_categories":[
                                {
                                    "name":"biscuits"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"cookies"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"bhujia"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"mixture"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"packaged-raw",
                            "child_categories":[
                                {
                                    "name":"noodles"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"pasta"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"macaroni"
                                },
                                 {
                                    "name":"spreads"
                                },
                                 {
                                    "name":"sauces"
                                },
                                 {
                                    "name":"ready-to-eat"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"chocs"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"pickles&chutney"
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
               }
            ]
        }
      
    ]
}
```

Each categories have sub categories,with up level parent_id, once first level category added, it should take that id, add it into child category. example structure below

```
{
  _id: "1",
  parent_category_id: null, // 1st level category
  name:"food"
}

{
  _id:2,
  parent_category_id: 1,
  name: "non-frozen"
}

{  
  _id: 3,
  parent_category_id: 2,
  name: "non-branded"
}
{
  _id: 4,
  parent_category_id: 3,
  name: "food-grains"
}

and so on...
```

```
 let payload = req.payload
              let obj1 = {
                    "name": payload.name,
                    "parent_category_id": null,
                    "created_by": userId,
                    "updated_by": userId
                }
                let parent_category = await Category.create(obj1)
            if (!!payload.childCategories){
                  payload.childCategories.forEach(async item => {
                    if(!!item){
                        let obj2 = {
                            "name": item.name,
                            "parent_category_id": parent_category._id,
                            "created_by": userId,
                            "updated_by": userId
                        }
                        let parent_category1 = await Category.create(obj2)
                        if (!!item.childCategories){
                            payload.childCategories.forEach(async item1 => {
                                let obj3 = {
                                    "name": item1.name,
                                    "parent_category_id": parent_category1._id,
                                    "created_by": userId,
                                    "updated_by": userId
                                }
                                let parent_category2 = await Category.create(obj3)
                            })
                        }
                    }

                  })
                }
```

Comment: Can you also [edit] your question to add a [mcve]? Followed by explanation of what your current code does and what you expect from it.

Comment: I think, i have tried static way of adding data, but the code should be dynamically find and add data into db, above i have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quick thought was to solve the problem with the recursive function. It can be solved in other ways as well. But I like recursive functions. They are legible.

```
async function addCategory(payload, parent = null) {
    const category = await Category.create({
      name: payload.name,
      parent_category_id: parent ? parent.id : null,
      created_by: userId,
      updated_by: userId
    });

    if(Array.isArray(payload.child_categories)) {
      for(const child of payload.child_categories) {
        addCategory(child, category);
      }
    }
}
```